# Excel Macro to run automatically for change in cells at different times independent of each other

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which will be used as a form by a number of users, and based on a few pull down boxes selection, a number of cells will change value (Independently of each other).

I have several macros which I want to run when the cells change (again independently, not collectively)

I already have one which runs using worksheet change by target value within the worksheet, but can't get anymore to work with this code.

A bit of a novice when it comes to this sort of stuff and need some help - using latest version of excel.

Comment: "... but can't get anymore to work with this code."  What happens when you try?

Comment: nothing, my excel code for the change by value is as below, but I have two other cells which will be used to run up to four different macro's - depending on the selection criteria.  The macros are all pretty simple - if cell =1, cut and paste something, else if cell =2, cut and paste something else type code.  have seen on various places online that one only change by value code can be used, surely there is a way round this which is simple enough for a novice like me?

Comment: A `Worksheet_Change` event is just like any other piece of code.  You can easily program it to do either one thing or many things, dependent on what cells were changed (e.g. if cell D1 was changed, do something, else if a cell in column H was changed, do something else, etc).  Why don't you post **in your question** what you tried, and we should be able to work out how to help you fix it so that it **does** do something.  (Well, someone else will help you - I'm calling it a night now.)

Comment: OK I will do later today

Comment: This is the code I am using in the page

Comment: This is the First subroutine code I am using in the page

    Sheets("2.2 Report").Select
    If ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value = "" Then
        Application.Run ("move_cursor_to_second_item")
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value = "1" Then
        Application.Run ("Baker_ISTO")
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value = "2" Then
        Range (D14)
    End If

Comment: The next two subs follow on from the one above and are

Sheets("Support").Select
    Range("Q2:S3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("2.2 Report").Select
    Range("G12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A18:C18").Select 

and

Range("A17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PLEASE RECHECK SCREEN ORDER STATUS BEFORE PROCEDING"

I have two others which work fine, but none of the above will work

Comment: Please paste the code into the question itself (it's nearly impossible to read in comments), including the `Sub` statement itself for each of the subroutines, and ensure you include the `Worksheet_Change` subroutine that you are using.